# ActiveMQ NMS: Using transport.requesttimeout with failover transport

Tags: c#, .net, nms

To try and mitigate any hangs that may come about during problems with ActiveMQ connectivity in my application, I'm looking at adding the following parameter to my broker connection string within my application:

```
?transport.requesttimeout=10000
```

According to [this resource](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2008/06/04/using-nms/), this looks as if it will help deal with these incidents.

However, I cannot seem to get this to work with my current failover connection string, which looks like this:

```
failover:(tcp://masterbroker:61616,tcp://slavebroker:61616)?keepAlive=true
```

Adding it in thusly:

```
failover:(tcp://masterbroker:61616,tcp://slavebroker:61616)?keepAlive=true&transport.requesttimeout=10000
```

Or, alternatively like this:

```
failover:(tcp://masterbroker:61616?transport.requesttimeout=10000,tcp://slavebroker:61616?transport.requesttimeout=10000)?keepAlive=true
```

... both seem to cause NMS exceptions or failures to connect.

This may seem a relatively trivial question, but how can I specify transport specific directives within this type of connection string?

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10893701/823040. For failover mode you need **transport.startupMaxReconnectAttempts**, **transport.timeout** or related options. Full list of options: http://activemq.apache.org/nms/activemq-uri-configuration.html. Transport.requesttimeout is not a valid directive for failover protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You should always add what version of NMS.ActiveMQ you are using when asking these questions as the behaviour between versions cam vary.  Assuming you are using the latest version the I'd expect a NMSException from the first form if you tried to connect to a broker and it wasn't running after about 10 seconds since, that's what the URI is telling it to do, the second URI is invalid as the only options that are applicable to the inner URI's of the failover configuration are the one's for the type of transport being called out, in this case TCP.

It might be better to take a step back and explain what you are trying to accomplish here as I don't really know what the reason you are applying the request timeout option.  In most cases I would not recommend this option.

Also the keepAlive option will have no affect here as its not being applied to the tcp transports so its just going to be ignored.  Beyond that tcp socket keep alive is practically useless as it only kicks in once every two hours or so, the tcp transports will do their own hearbeating for you unless you disable the inactivity monitor so their's no need for keepAlive=true.

If you can provide some more info on what the exceptions you are seeing are or what problem you are trying to solve with the request timeout I could probably answer your question better.

-Tim  www.fusesource.com

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of NMS - v1.5.0. Essentially the problems I am try to counter are failures in the broker causing issues within my applications (which is using synchronous sends)

Comment: Still not clear on what the request timeout is supposed to be fixing for you, just using the failover transport alone will detect dropped connections and reconnect to a new broker for you.  You can configure reconnect attempts limits and delay values on the failover transport as well in case you don't want the client to hang on the connection.Start() method if no broker is running.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `transport.requesttimeout=10000` use `connection.RequestTimeout=10000`

Comment: Can you explain why the use of `connection` helped to solve the problem? Give little explanation on why the OP need to accept your solution