# ActiveMQ NMS: connection.start() hangs with Failover protocol when broker is down

Tags: activemq-classic, nms, apache-nms

I have C# application using nms.activemq 1.5.0.

When my application starts it tries to connect to the broker using failover protocol (I have two brokers in master-slave configuration).
If both brokers down my application is stuck in wait because of the `connection.start()`.
I tried every bit of info i found on the web - I tried every attribute of the failover protocol, also tried setting the connection timeout, tried `transport.requesttimeout`.

I also tried a newer version of nms.activemq, but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Any idea on what can cause this problem or any workaround?

Comment: It is very weird, but in version 1.5.5 it hangs (using failover mode) even on **connection.ClientId** property assignment, what is considered as anti-patterns in .NET, because properties should represent simple, fast, non-blocking operations.

Answer (score 13):

After mining google results fI found [this thread](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/failover-startupMaxReconnectAttempts-doesn-t-do-anything-td3735372.html)

Tim Bish answered the developer there that in NMS there is a prefix **transport.*** that need to added to all transport properties.

my original uri was:

```
failover://(tcp://A,tcp://B)?randomize=true&startupMaxReconnectAttempts=1&timeout=2000
```

and now my URI is (pay attention on **transport.*** prefix):

```
failover://(tcp://A,tcp://B)?transport.randomize=true&transport.startupMaxReconnectAttempts=1&transport.timeout=2000
```

which is working and I handle the exception thrown and continue with my App.

Enjoy